# Error: "Picklist value in picklist not found" while deploying using ANT

Tags: deployment, picklist, ant

on my account object, I created a picklist field - testPicklist1__c. The picklist field has various values in it. One picklist value is "abc t" & its API name is "abc". I retrieved the Account object using ANT & tried to deploy to another Salesforce org using ANT. I got the below error message -:
[image]

Error Message says -:  "Picklist value: abc t in picklist: testPicklist1__c not found".

When I viewed the Account.object file I found that under "testPicklist1" field definition, the picklist value is shown with full name "abc" like this `<fullName>abc</fullName>` as shown below -:

```
<fields>
    <fullName>testPicklist1__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>testPicklist1</label>
    <picklist>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>abc</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>  
    </picklist>
</fields>
```

Wheras in "AOC" record type definition under the enabled picklist value, this picklist is being referenced using "abc t" as the full name like this `<fullName>abc t</fullName>` as shown below -:

```
<recordTypes>
    <fullName>AOC</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <label>AOC</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>testPicklist1__c</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>abc t</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</recordTypes>
```

Is this what causing the above error ? How can I remove this error & deploy successfully without manually doing changes ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would pull the data from the source org again in the expectation that the values would be consistent. Or manually change.

Comment: Pulling again does not solve the problem. I think it is a bug when we retrieve picklist values using ANT from an org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh! I was missing the latest metadata API version which is for the picklist API name feature that was added in Spring ’17 release. I retrieved after changing package.xml to version 39 and then deployed and it worked. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names.html